# How to run a close view function from a different class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

I have created a SignUp view(`class SignUp: UICollectionViewCell`) and I have a code to close that view again e.g. with a close button.

I'm launching that view in a different class (`class SignUpLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`) and the code to close is also in that class.

Now I want to close that view when the registration is successful. In my SignUp class I run this:

```
    let signUpLauncher = SignUpLauncher()
    func handleClose(){
        signUpLauncher.handleClose()
    }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in
            if let error = err {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                guard let uid = user?.uid else{
                    return
                }
                //Successfully authenticated user
                print("Sucess")

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "myURL.com/")
                let usersRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid)
                let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
                usersRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    print("Saved user successfully into DB")
                    self.handleClose()

                })

            }
        })
```

This is the `handleClose()` function in the `SignUpLauncher` class:

```
     func handleClose(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.closeButton.alpha = 0

            if let  window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
                self.self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
                self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.navBar.frame.width, height: 65)
                self.closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.width - 34 ,y: window.frame.height + 30,width: 18,height: 18)
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is, nothing is happening. I think, it has something to do with the `self` but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You make it sound like you're trying to close a collection view cell. You should not do that. The collection view owns and manages its cells. If that's not what you mean then you need to explain better.

Comment: You say "I'm launching Signup from SignupLauncher." What do you mean "Launching"? Apps get launched. Views get added to superviews. View controllers get pushed or presented. It also isn't clear what kind of classes `Signup` and `SignupLauncher` are.

Comment: For a better understanding: I made a custom View ('SignUp') with a UICollectionViewCell as a construct. I don't use UICollectionViewController.

Comment: @DuncanC The 'Launcher' contains the showView() and the handleClose(). They're animating the Cell on and off screen.

Comment: Collection view cells are not designed to be, and should not be, used outside of a collection view. There is no reason to do so and plenty of reasons not to.

Comment: The rest of your setup is still not at all clear. How are your various views added into the view hierarchy? What kind of object is your "launcher"? Is it a view controller?

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. You should not use collection view cells outside of a collection view. You create a new object and expect it to point to a button on your current view controller. It won't. You should put the IBAction methods for your view controller in your view controller.

You need to stop and go read up on the basics of iOS app design. Right now you are getting more wrong than right,  and you're just going to get frustrated.